# No eight digit perfect fourth powers with distinct digits and not containing 3.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

**Problem:** Prove that there are no perfect fourth powers that have eight distinct digits in  their base 10 representation and also don't contain 3 as a digit.

My attempt:
Since the problem is about digits I tried to work with modulo 9.
Since fourth powers can be $0, 1, 4, 7$  modulo 9, i am able to conclude that the only cases left check are numbers who digits are permutations of  one of the following sets:

$\{1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 \}$,

$\{1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 \}$,

$\{1,2,  4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 0 \}$,

$\{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7,  9, 0 \}$
Also, checking modulo $27$, I eliminated the last two cases but I am unable to proceed furthere.

So, someone please help.

Comment: If worst comes to worst, there are fewer than fifty to check: $50^4$ has seven digits and $100^4$ has nine.

Comment: Did the question say eight distinct _non-zero_ digits?

Comment: @Michael, yes of course. But since its a contest problem I think there should be a less computational solution.  Oops!, I forgot to write that it is a problem from  a contst called Proofathon 2013.

Comment: Michael, no it did not. If it were non zero digits then the problem becomes trivial bvy modulo 9